# Can I install android studio in ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, android-studio

Should I install android studio in ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS having 3 GB of ram and 5 GB of swap so is it feasible to install android studio?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can perfectly install and run *Android Studio* with that specs.

I have it running in a 2,0Ghz Centrino from the Core2Duo era with 2gb of ram and 4 gb swap, and runs pretty well.

However you should have some considerations in mind:

- You should avoid using android emulator due to memory limitations, use then a real android device.
- Oracle JVM is recommended over OpenJDK for GUI apps like *Android Studio*. You can install it following this instructions:

  `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java`

  `sudo apt-get update`

  `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer`

  At this point you'll be prompted to accept the license agreement, use cursor keys to select *Yes* and press Enter.

  Then run: `sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default` to update system defaults.

Anyway don't expect same performance as a desktop i7 + 8gb of ram (I have it too), is very usable, but there are tasks such compiling, indexing, etc, which may take a bit longer.

Comment: It would be nice to include installation steps instead of putting a link.

Comment: @Rahul, Yes you are right, I updated my answer.